# Generating an oblique (slanted) font in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, slanted, font-metrics

With LuaLaTeX, I am using an OpenType font family ([Dolly Pro](http://www.underware.nl/fonts/dolly/try)) with roman small caps but no italic small caps. My block quote style uses italics, which I like, but one of my quotations has the abbreviation “PM” in small caps. I’d like to generate a slanted, or oblique, version of the roman small caps to substitute, accessible via `textsl`. I think this would look less offensive than either upright small caps or full caps.

(If you think that font surgery is unacceptable even for these purposes, let me know in the comments!)

As the following MWE demonstrates, the small caps are not linked to the roman or italic families—although this should not restrict the creation of slanted versions any more than it would otherwise.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\fontspec{Dolly Pro Regular Italic}
At 4:00 \textsl{\fontspec{Dolly Pro Regular Small Caps}pm} he set off.
\end{document}
```

[image: Dolly Pro italic, with no slanted small caps]

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I couldn't find `AutoFakeSlant` in the documentation. However, using `AutoFakeSlant=0.1`, combined with `\textit` or `\textsl`, works well. Please put this suggestion in an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your font does not provide that font-feature, you might use the option `AutoFakeSlant` from `fontspec`.

I had to use some other font and the mix of small caps and italics looks bad here, but you see how it's done. I got the feeling that the space on the left side appears to be very big when slanted letters are used. Therefore I added some kerning in order to show you this as well. You may, however, want to introduce some new macro if such constructs appear more often.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\begin{document}
    \textit{At 4:00 \kern-.1em{\fontspec[AutoFakeSlant=.3]{EBGaramond12-AllSC.otf}pm} he set off.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not bad! Certainly acceptable if it only appears once in a book.